# Python - losing last char in String while splitting/mapping

Tags: python

I found an issue with converting a String in multiple substrings with a given length.

I have a String of binaries, which I want to split into groups of five.
However with my method right now it seems that I lose some last bits if the length of the String is not dividable by 5. How could I improve my code?

I start splitting from the front, and If there is a remainder, I want to add as many '0' to the string, to make the last 'packet' also contain 5 values

```
list_5bit_words = list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(binary_i)]*5)))
print(list_5bit_words)
```

With '0100011001000110' I get this: ['01000', '11001', '00011']
But I want this : ['01000', '11001', '00011', '00000']

Comment: Try: `[('0000' + binary_i[i:i+5])[-5:] for i in range(0, len(binary_i), 5)]`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add as many 0's as you need to de string `binary_i` in order to make it divisible by 5.

```
binary_i += '0'*(5-len(binary_i)%5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward solution is to simply implement the logic you described: check the remainder, and pad it with extra '0's at the end:

```py
binary_i = '0100011001000110'

group_size = 5
list_5bit_words = list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(binary_i)] * group_size)))
remainder = binary_i[len(list_5bit_words)*group_size:]
padding_len = group_size-len(remainder)
list_5bit_words.append(remainder+'0'*padding_len)
print(list_5bit_words) # Output ['01000', '11001', '00011', '00000']
```

However, you could simply append '0000' (4 zeroes) to the end of your string before starting to chunk it, so the last group will always be filled with 0 up to 5 chars, but no "new group" will be created:

```py
list_5bit_words = list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(binary_i+'0000')] * 5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code should work:

```
def split_string(string):
    splitted = []
    string += "0" * (4 - ((len(string) - 1) % 5))
    for i in range(0, len(string), 5):
        splitted.append(string[i : i + 5])
    return splitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do that with [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) module for splitting and [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) method for filling with zeros when needed:

```py
from textwrap import wrap

list_5bit_words = [chunk.ljust(5, '0') for chunk in wrap(binary_i, 5)]
```